# Can we set cloudwatch log retention days in /etc/awslogs/awslogs.conf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

As we know we can put something like this in `awslogs.conf` file:

```
[/var/log/mylog]
file = /var/log/mylog.log
log_group_name = mylog
log_stream_name = mystream
datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f
```

What other parameters can we set in this file? I am looking to set the log retention days - is it possible?

Answer (score 12):

The `awslogs.conf` file contains settings for the [agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) process, which is responsible for putting your log files into **CloudWatch Logs**. Managing the underlying **log groups** is out of the scope of it's responsibilities.

Assuming that the log group is created in the `user-data` script (comments), you could add an additional [command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-retention-policy.html) for setting the retention period there:

```
aws logs put-retention-policy --log-group-name mylog --retention-in-days 7
```

Answer (score 6):

For changing log data retention in CloudWatch you can:

1. go to CloudWatch console
2. choose **Logs** in the navigation pane
3. find your log group
4. change the value of the **Expire Event After** column

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) you can find a list of other parameters you can set in the config file.

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi. But we log groups are created by ECS user data.  So it would be great if we can setup this retention days in user data instead of going to console after.